# Orthophoto Rwanda Free Download?

Tags: data-request, images, aerial-photography, africa

I'm looking for Image datas for East Africa. Specifically for Rwanda. Does anyone know if such data are available at all free? My target is to digitize roads and buildings with the help of image datas.Thanks in advance.

Comment: OSM has access to data, and is a great way to get roads and buildings that are already done.

Comment: Hello am survey how can I get orthophotos of Rwanda?